# Firewall configurator not opening after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: gui, firewall, 16.04

after upgrading to 16.04 the firewall configurator is not showing up any more.

The firewall itself (UFW) seems to be running as:

```
sudo ufw status
```

returns `active` and my rules.

running the GUI from the command line I get:

```
(gufw.py:9277): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2:19: Theming engine 'adwaita' not found

(gufw.py:9277): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-3_10.css:12:16: Theming engine 'adwaita' not found

** (gufw.py:9277): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0' referenced by the typelib: libgbm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py:117: Warning: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type 'void'
  self.web_content = WebKit.WebView()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw.py", line 29, in <module>
    gufw = Gufw(controler.get_frontend())
  File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py", line 79, in __init__
self._set_objects_name()
  File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py", line 117, in _set_objects_name
    self.web_content = WebKit.WebView()
TypeError: could not get a reference to type class
```

UPDATE: This problem persists, if there is anybody not facing this on 16.04, please drop me comment.